# UISegmentedControl like in iTunes/App Store apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to get a UISegmentedControl like is in the iTunes app and App store app,
where you select between Top Paid, Top Free and Top Grossing, its a bar style except more blue. It goes above a table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = 7;`

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to simply use integers like that. What happens if Apple decides to change the meaning of "7"? Use constants instead.

Comment: Then I'll update my app. I'm really not too worried about it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the normal UISegmentedControl class and use the property to change the style as needed.

(See *Style* popup menu on the right!)

[image: screenshot]

You can also set the `segmentedControlStyle` property of the control to one of the following values:

```
typedef enum {
   UISegmentedControlStylePlain,
   UISegmentedControlStyleBordered,
   UISegmentedControlStyleBar,
   UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled,
} UISegmentedControlStyle;
```

Comment: I had thought of that, but it doesn't match the intended style, which is like a mini toolbar, with blue background.